# How are Kubernetes CPU limits enforced?

Tags: kubernetes

Are Kubernetes CPU limits "hard" limits?

Say I have a node with 1 CPU with two pods scheduled and running/ready/active, each with `requests.limits.cpu` of 500m. Pod A uses up 1 CPU for a while--this is normal/allowed. Eventually, pod B wants some CPU. Will Kubernetes (or Linux) make sure that pod B can get the .5 CPU it asks for?

### Update on Thu Jun 23 16:55:25 UTC 2016

I'm still looking for a definitive answer, but it sounds like these may be hard limits in Linux/Docker. `@danielmartins` [wrote this](https://kubernetes.slack.com/archives/kubernetes-users/p1466620520005883) in the [k8s slack channel](https://kubernetes.slack.com):

> I believe you can find this out by running `docker inspect` on the containers in which you set the limits. Checking one of my containers, I see that Kubernetes set `CpuPeriod`, `CpuQuota` for them. The Docker docs (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/) mention the CFS documentation (https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/scheduler/sched-bwc.txt), and from the information there, it seems that these are hard limits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For kubernetes v1.2+, CPU resource limits are enforced using hardcapping, and requests are enforced using shares.

The change was noted in the [release note](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md/#v120) and there is an [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/27605) open to update the documentation.

Comment: Since I had to look it up: hardcapping means that the limit cannot be exceeded, even if the CPU has more cycles available.

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes just manages the containers. As far as I know, it is actually the container engine (Docker, rkt) which implements the CPU limitation. That limitation is not a hard limit, as you already observed. but rather a percentage of the available resources.

Kubernetes (if set up with monitoring for this purpose), takes the used resource values and uses them to determine if you need a new pod (assuming you have set up some auto scaling). Kubernetes can not rate limit the existing pod since it is not actually running the containers in the pod.